# Can a brewery in California fill any growler?

Tags: laws, growlers

There has been some confusion around the laws regarding "refillable containers" in California.  At times, I have been told that a brewery *cannot* refill another brewery's growler.  At other times, I have been told that a brewery *may* (or by their discretion, may not) refill.  I own growlers from at least 3 different breweries, and I have friends who have many more -- it makes sense to me that I should be able to take any clean container to a brewery which offers growlers, and have it filled.

What do the actual laws of California state, regarding who can refill and into what vessels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can, provided that they:

- Cover up existing labels
- Add their own label containing the brewery name, beer name, and abv.
- Are a brewery (bars and retailers cannot).

You're not alone in being confused, though.  A lot of breweries didn't really know either, and as a result decided not to, just to be safe.

Further complicating the issue is that many breweries just don't want to, either because they make money on *their* growlers or because it's a pain to deal with the labeling when their bar is busy.

SFGate has [a decent article](http://www.sfgate.com/wine/brew/article/California-eases-up-on-buying-beer-to-go-4888968.php) for further reading.

Comment: Other reasons I've seen given: they're only equipped for their style of growler (sanitation, replacement caps, physical design of the growler fill station) and that they want their beer going home with their full branding. http://russianriverbrewing.com/growler-filling-policy/

Comment: You might also end up with questions of open container laws, though these might not be the brewery's responsibility.

Comment: For what it's worth the law is similar in Indiana, except the new label that covers the original only needs to have the brewery's name.